# jquery Lightbox plugin not working when uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I really hope someone can help me as I'm having trouble with Lightbox. It works perfectly locally but now that I have uploaded it to my server the images just open in a new window.
I installed Firebug to try to find out what was going on and it comes up with this error $(".portfolio-item a").lightBox is not a function
I have also tried changing permissions but to no avail.

My site is http://www.peppermintdesign.com.au/portfolio.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's in the wrong place :). The error is

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.peppermintdesign.com.au/js/jquery.lightBox-0.5.min.js"

So the lightbox javascript file is missing on the server side.

Install that Firebug and use the javascript console. That will help you big time developing frontends ;).

Answer (score 0):

It's because this link does not exist http://www.peppermintdesign.com.au/js/jquery.lightBox-0.5.min.js

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /js/jquery.lightBox-0.5.min.js was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

upload again jquery.lightBox-0.5.min.js to your js folder